# Can nginx run both for gitlab and taiga.io on the same VM?

Tags: nginx, gitlab, unicorn, gunicorn

I having troubles running [GitLab](https://gitlab.com) and [Taiga.io](https://taiga.io) on the same VM (i.e. sharing the same IP). Both use nginx. My VM runs Debian 8.

I have followed the classical [Omnibus installation](http://doc.gitlab.com/omnibus/) of GitLab for Debian 8, and when I enter the IP of my VM on a browser, gitlab is served correctly, and all goes well.

Then I shut it down (`sudo gitlab-ctl stop`), and I installed Taiga, following the [production environment setup](http://taigaio.github.io/taiga-doc/dist/setup-production.html). According to the doc it uses Gunicorn and Circus for taiga-back (which serves REST APIs), and nginx for serving the frontend. Once `/etc/nginx/sites-available|enabled/taiga`, `~/taiga-back/settings/local.py` and `~/taiga-front-dist/dist/conf.json` are all setup using the same IP address, and nginx is restarted (`sudo service nginx restart`) all goes well too.

Now, it is possible to change all the aforementioned Taiga IP addresses with a different port (say `8080`), restart nginx, and Taiga is now served from the IP adress:8080. All fine!

When I restart GitLab (`sudo gitlab-ctl start`), it says that everything starts smoothly. But when I try to access it (on default port 80) I get a `502`!

If I switch down Taiga and restart GitLab, hoho, GitLab is available! Basically, I can have them only separately, but not at the same time.

I also tried to keep Taiga on port 80, and move GitLab on port 8080 (by changing the port on the file `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and running `sudo gitlab-ctlr reconfigure`), but I never managed to run it successfully.

I have also tried to configure GitLab to use the system nginx (and not that embedded one), that is, the one used by Taiga. For that I disabled nginx on `gitlab.rb` following the [doc](http://doc.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-a-non-bundled-web-server), and using that omnibus (non-ssl) recipe:

```
## GitLab 8.3+
##
## Lines starting with two hashes (##) are comments with information.
## Lines starting with one hash (#) are configuration parameters that can be uncommented.
##
##################################
##        CONTRIBUTING          ##
##################################
##
## If you change this file in a Merge Request, please also create
## a Merge Request on https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/merge_requests
##
###################################
##         configuration         ##
###################################
##
## See installation.md#using-https for additional HTTPS configuration details.

upstream gitlab-workhorse {
  server unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket;
}

## Normal HTTP host
server {
  ## Either remove "default_server" from the listen line below,
  ## or delete the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default file. This will cause gitlab
  ## to be served if you visit any address that your server responds to, eg.
  ## the ip address of the server (http://x.x.x.x/)n 0.0.0.0:80 default_server;
  listen 80 default_server;
  #listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name gitlab.<replaced with company URL> <replace with VM IP address>; ## Replace
  server_tokens off; ## Don't show the nginx version number, a security best practice
  root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;

  ## See app/controllers/application_controller.rb for headers set

  ## Individual nginx logs for this GitLab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
    client_max_body_size 0;
    gzip off;

    ## https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    ## Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
    proxy_read_timeout      300;
    proxy_connect_timeout   300;
    proxy_redirect          off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab-workhorse;
  }
}
```

along with that for Taiga:

```
server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    server_name taiga.<replaced with company URL> <replace with VM IP address>; 

    large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    charset utf-8;

    access_log /opt/taiga/logs/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /opt/taiga/logs/nginx.error.log;

    # Frontend
    location / {
        root /opt/taiga/taiga-front-dist/dist/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # Backend
    location /api {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001/api;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    # Django admin access (/admin/)
    location /admin {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001$request_uri;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    # Static files
    location /static {
        alias /opt/taiga/taiga-back/static;
    }

    # Media files
    location /media {
        alias /opt/taiga/taiga-back/media;
    }
}
```

With these two configs in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`, after a restart (`sudo service nginx restart`) my Taiga server is accessible through port 8080, but strangely, the gitlab server isn't accessible anymore. No 502 but a connexion timeout!

Anyone knowing nginx with an idea? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the nginx config files for both gitlab and taiga - I've seen whats in the guide but for completeness can you post yours

Comment: Thanks @Drifter104 for checking this out. I've posted the nginx config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of my IT provider, we found a solution, which goes along the starting point of @Alex_hha answer: it was a mistake to bind Taiga to port 8080 ([LSNED](http://lsned.com)...)

So finally, I use the Debian installation of nginx in my VM as a reverse proxy, disabled the embedded nginx inside GitLab (by editing the `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` file) and configured both Taiga and Gitlab with configurations file inside `/etc/nginx/sites-available` (and symlinks to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`), as the following:

Taiga:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name taiga.<company URL> <VM IP address>;
```

and the remaining unchanged. And for Gitlab:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name gitlab.<company URL>;

    large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    charset utf-8;

    access_log /opt/gitlab/logs/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /opt/gitlab/logs/nginx.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    }
}
```

So both are accessed through the port 80, but given the URL of the request, the right service is called. Note the absence of `default_server` in GitLab config.

This combination of config makes all GitLab traffic going to GitLab and anything else (even invalid URL) ending up on Taiga service.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use port 8080 for Taiga or at least do not bind nginx to localhost:8080. For Taiga you can bind nginx to some specific external interface, for example something like the following

```
server {
    listen 192.168.127.1:8080;
    ...
}
```

I'm using Gitlab and Jenkins on the same machine without any problem. Both of them on port 8080

```
# lsof -n -P -i tcp:8080
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    18983 jenkins  155u  IPv6 639617      0t0  TCP 192.168.88.87:8080 (LISTEN)
ruby    19098     git    9u  IPv4 113752      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8080 (LISTEN)
ruby    19141     git    9u  IPv4 113752      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8080 (LISTEN)
ruby    19144     git    9u  IPv4 113752      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8080 (LISTEN)
ruby    19147     git    9u  IPv4 113752      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8080 (LISTEN)
ruby    19150     git    9u  IPv4 113752      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8080 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: I've tried your solution (replacing `192.168.127.1` by the IP of my VM). But when running `sudo nginx -t` I get: `nginx: [emerg] bind() to <external IP>:8080 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address)`

Comment: Could I run both GitLab and Taiga on port 80? How to do that? How do you access them then, from outside?

Comment: You can check with lsof who has taken the port

Comment: hm... lsof shows 4 lines like that `ruby    1109  git   13u  IPv4  14114      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8080 (LISTEN)` Could it be gitlab then? I'm lost.

Comment: Are you sure that default vhost in nginx is not active? You can check specific interface with "lsof -n -P -iTCP@192.168.127.1:8080"

Comment: Nope, I've deleted the default vhost in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

Comment: Check with lsof